# Spring List<MultipartFile> returns one even though no files have been selected

Tags: java, spring, jsp, multipartform-data

I have a form that allows a user to select multiple images to upload to the server. The problem is that in my controller `files.size()` returns `one` even though I have not selected any file to upload. So the line `if(files != null && files.size() > 0)` always gets executed.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/advert/add", method=POST)
public void insertAdverts(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, 
        @ModelAttribute("fileUpload") FileUpload fileUpload)
                throws NumberFormatException, IOException, IllegalStateException, 
                ServletException, FileUploadException{

    //Get uploaded files and store them
    List<MultipartFile> files = fileUpload.getFiles();
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{
        if(files != null && files.size() > 0){
            for(MultipartFile image:files){
                String fileName = image.getOriginalFilename();
                String[] fileSplit = fileName.split("\\.");
                fileNames.add(fileName);

                File uploadedFile = new File(uploadDirectory+"\\"+fileName);
                uploadedFile.createNewFile();
                image.transferTo(uploadedFile);
            }
        }
```

Here is FileUpload Class

```
public class FileUpload implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int menuId;
private int subMenuId;
private String adLocation;
private String adSubject;
private String adBody;
private String contactNo;
private String contactEmail;
private String fileName;
private List<MultipartFile> files = null;
.....
```

and the jsp form

```
<form:form id = "add-advert-form" method="post" action="/AdPost/advert/add" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="fileUpload">
        ...
    <form:input type="file" id="adPictures" accept="image/*" 
               name="files[]" multiple="multiple" path="files"/>
</form:form>
```

Can someone please tell me why `List.size()` is returning `one` instead of `zero` and how to get the correct list size.

This is what files looks like in debug window:

[image: This is what files looks like in debug window]

[image: fileItem]

Comment: I don't know, but I'm wondering what's in the `fileItem`. Maybe that gives a hint on what's going on.

Comment: I'm face this same problem and was about to ask this question. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, what I do is checking the first item size in my list.
This my code using groovy

```
if(!files.get(0).isEmpty){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general information which might help someone else and absolutely makes sense for this question.

According To [this official](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) Mozilla Developer link here is the note regarding input type file.

So just check on backend what is the value for the file parameter by debugging.

> Note: If multiple files are selected, the string represents the first
>   selected file. JavaScript can access the other files through the
>   input's files property. If no file is yet selected, the string is ""
>   (empty). The string is prefixed with C:\fakepath\, to prevent
>   malicious software from guessing the user's file structure.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently having this problem and asked the same question. I just came up with this solution. IN you case:

```
if(files[0].getSize() != 0)
```

I know this is late but hope it will help someone in the future.